# I've got an input which it's type is set to hidden, I need to change it's type to text. Can't seem to figure this out or if it's possible with js

Tags: javascript

I've got an input which it's type is set to hidden, I need to change it's type to text. Can't seem to figure this out or if it's possible with js

Comment: can you share some code ?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('myinput').type='text';
```

Tested in IE 9 and Chrome 25. You can see it working on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V4NmC/

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you'd do something like:

```
$('#elementId').attr('type', 'text');
```

Comment: It isn't said if jQuery is in use in the te's project and including jQuery only for such a simple function is overexaggerated.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("textinput").setAttribute('type', 'text');`

Answer (score 0):

Why change it's type? Can't you just create it as a text input and then change it's display value?

```
document.getElementById("InputName").style.diplay="inline";
```

or to change it back

```
document.getElementById("InputName").style.diplay="none";
```